# Creating a job with credentials in jenkins only in command lines

Tags: jenkins, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, credentials, jobs

I am only allowed to work with the command line terminal on Ubuntu.
I need to create a job in Jenkins with security credentials.

I already installed Jenkins in my machine, but the access is open. If I set-up security credentials on Jenkins, how can I specify these on the command line?

Comment: You have not really asked a question here. I'm not sure what you using command line on Ubuntu has to do with Jenkins. Can you not access the Jenkins web page using another computer?

Comment: Ok. I know that is possible to configure jenkins only using command lines in Ubuntu. So, I need to make that configuration with a username, password and a job. But unfortunately I did not find this specific command yet.

Comment: Ok. I've updated your question based on what I understood. Please check and make sure it is what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Check out the SSH plugin in Jenkins. Credentials (usually an SSH key) are specified under the Jenkins settings.

Comment: Thank you Sagar. That sounds better.

Comment: Hi Mark, I was trying to do that with a private key that was generated here : https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys. But when I run the command "java -jar _jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -i /home/ubuntu2/.ssh/id_rsa create-job test", it dont work. just return a exception error. I'll post it below.


  I don't know what I need to change anymore!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Failed to load key: /home/ubuntu2/.ssh/id_rsa
 at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:228)
 at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:199)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: PEM is encrypted, but no password was specified
 at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.PEMDecoder.decode(PEMDecoder.java:318)
 at hudson.cli.CLI.loadKey(CLI.java:301)
 at hudson.cli.CLI.loadKey(CLI.java:294)
 at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:226)
 ... 1 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Generate a public ssh-key in the user you want to work with from the command line:

   ```
    ssh-keygen
   ```

   Just press enter whenever yo are asked to enter some value.
2. Copy the content of the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.
3. Go to your jenkins home screen in a browser and login with a user with full access, Then click on the right on **Users** and then on the user you are currently logged with. Then click on **settings** (or configuration??).
4. In the field **SSH public keys** paste the content of the `id_rsa.pub` file. Save the changes.

And that's all! Now you are able to work with jenkins from the command line.

**From the command line**

The following is the configuration file of my jenkins main user (with all the privileges). Pay attention to the setting `<authorizedKeys>`. You should paste there the public ssh key. I haven't made that, but surely if you add the necessary lines to your config file it works. The file is in `/path_to_jenkins/users/user_name/config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<user>
 <fullName>admin</fullName>
 <description></description>
 <properties>
  <jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
   <apiToken>pP08W9tzs2jlCrVCY9I2o6y2RNu3Huw85Y2f99/Uif7dia1W7piGpzsrpstln/jw</apiToken>
  </jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
  <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.UserCredentialsProvider_-UserCredentialsProperty plugin="credentials@1.4">
   <credentials/>
  </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.UserCredentialsProvider_-UserCredentialsProperty>
  <hudson.tasks.Mailer_-UserProperty plugin="mailer@1.4">
   <emailAddress>admin@mail.com</emailAddress>
  </hudson.tasks.Mailer_-UserProperty>
  <hudson.model.MyViewsProperty>
   <primaryViewName></primaryViewName>
   <views>
    <hudson.model.AllView>
      <owner class="hudson.model.MyViewsProperty" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>Alle</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    </hudson.model.AllView>
  </views>
</hudson.model.MyViewsProperty>
<hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>
 <passwordHash>1DF2ykjkkkjkkQXW</passwordHash>
</hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>
<org.jenkinsci.main.modules.cli.auth.ssh.UserPropertyImpl>
 
<authorizedKeys>ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA4P1b/5RpibQgDZpKPD7lTQLjtyMrIQH43ns62PO72koL9zJe6qrAYcTIDNOUvSYNYyKfrgt6Z5zB8MvvENQLWezDKTWNXINhZml0PxOlc9ZaHbQX6UqyFbTS6o+ZEGs+K92Yi/XwK5hTmN5Igsw5BQYEs5cOsd5H2PoEZdhK1X0XAEBX/+p6aNy585+/scgZj0jSIvcX+pnzsCJLKmeYadlLnbrvebf9u6pu8MI9RuAY5dvPfpSL4WynWwS1QvY4z535TqPaaAlM3qXqH0pcOlxgW1iUkJqti3JnnxpBNXLmXalmq+4/d7mUrRBx+HKbh5ZpNZad9vaelAjAsNg+uw== user@machine_name</authorizedKeys>
</org.jenkinsci.main.modules.cli.auth.ssh.UserPropertyImpl>
  <hudson.search.UserSearchProperty>
   <insensitiveSearch>false</insensitiveSearch>
  </hudson.search.UserSearchProperty>
 </properties>
</user>
```

Comment: Hi @Nicolás, but following your answer, I need enter in the browser to put those information. I cant do that because I need to find a way to set up credentials (user and password) just in from terminal. That is my main problem and my time is ending. There is another way?

Comment: Yeaa! It seems to me that we now are talking about the same problem. How did you generate this '<passwordHash>'?

Comment: I didin't edit directly the file, just set the configurations using the browser. Take into account that the password hash may be a encrypted value. I don't know how to manage all jenkins capabilities from the console. From what I know it's necessary to use the browser to make the first configurations, specially to set the users and passwords.

Comment: We found the right commands and now we are able to enter with user and password.. This tips helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't vote up to your answer. Any way, I'll open another discussion about how to correctly use ssh keys to run commands. This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706293/authentication-failed-no-private-key-accepted-jenkins-error

Comment: Hey. I've seen the new question. In the instruction you are tryng to run, I think you have to pass as parameter the public key (`id_rsa.pub`), not the private key (`id_rsa`). (Sorry, I cannot comment on questions that are not mine). 

Other thing: With the jenkins-cli you have the option **login**, so I suppose you don't have to use ssh keys, just user and password. It's just and idea.

Comment: you are right about the public key(`id_rsa.pub`). Here we did something like that: *First we use gedit on terminal for opening the id_rsa.pub. *Second we copy the content into your config.xml above, where is said `<authorizedKeys>`. And finally, we pasted this .xml file into `/path_to_jenkins/users/user_name/`. After that, we just run the command `root@ubuntu:/var/lib/jenkins# java -jar _jenkins-cli.jar -s http://my_localhost:8080/ restart`. Was beautiful to see how the command was effective. Again.. thank you so much for your tips. Hope I can answer some problem too!

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the starting prompt location to the folder in which the jar file is located. For example, if your jar file's location and name is:

```
C:\Users\Tod\file.jar
```

you can do two commands:

```
cd C:\Users\Tod
java -jar file.jar
```