# How to resolve the error : "Unable to access jarfile jenkins-cli.jar"

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to run commands on jenkins in a Ubuntu machine, but when I try do any thing through terminal, like a simple restart just for a test,is displayed that error:

```
Unable to access jarfile jenkins-cli.jar
```

So, my jenkins-cli.jar may be in the wrong place. Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember yo have to download the jenkins-cli.jar file (I think even if you are working where jenkins is hosted). Go to `http://jenkins_url/cli` (in my case is `http://host_machine:8080/jenkins/cli`). There you have the link to download the file. Save it where you want.

Then try tu run an instruction. For example, for building a project run

```
java -jar /path_to_cli-file/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins_url build job_name
```

Remember that the user you are working with should have the right permissions to execute the action.

I've just tested that, so I hope it works.

If you still have problems don't hesistate to ask.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Nicolás. Was the location of my jenkins-cli.jar was in the wrong place. Unfortunately has born another problem. How can I set up credentials in my jenkins through terminal? I've tried 'java -jar _jenkins-cli.jar -s http://host_machine:8080 login --username myusername --password secret', but nothing. It generates that error: 'org.acegisecurity.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: Password is not set: myusername' and some other things. Do you know something about that?

Comment: Hey. I answered that in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570728/creating-a-job-with-credentials-in-jenkins-only-in-command-lines :). I hope it's clear.

Comment: @Nicolás Arias How can i automate this with docker, i mean how scripting need to be done?

Comment: @Hithesh From the documentation I see the `jenkins-cli.jar` is hosted on the Jenkins server at `https://JENKINS_URL/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar` IOf you are using a Linux server, you can add `wget https://JENKINS_URL/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar` to your script and then run the instruction I specified on the answer. You can add options to wget to set the download directory. For further reference visit https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/

Comment: i have created and have some problem in given link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024226/how-do-i-automate-running-the-jenkins-and-jenkins-cli Can u pls provide me some solutions for the same  @ Nicolás Arias

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your directory to where the jar file is? You can change director by typing "cd location" without the quotes, where location is the location of your jar file.

Comment: Yes. But I put the exact location when I try to run the command.

Comment: Hi @Garrett. It was that the problem. But now I have another problem with credencials. I've explained it in the Nicolás comment. If you know something about it, fell free to help. Thanks.